# Azure: Login failed for user

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, azure

What I have done:

- I added Resource group in Azure.
- Added Web Service with previous resource group.
- Added SQL Server Database with previous resource group.
- Retrieved generated connection string from this database and provided here username and password.
- Added this connection string to App Settings in Web Service.
- Published app via Visual Studio.

Problem:
I get this error when I tries to test this hosted app in azure, but on my local version of app and exactly this connection string everything works just fine..

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1418
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +470
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +777
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +114
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1637
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +267
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +132
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +246
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +509
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +238
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +331
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +916
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +413
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +116

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +377
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +35

[ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.]
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +266
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +84
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +89
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +63
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +91
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +227
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +846
   Hakon.HamiltonCargo.Web.NinjectWebCommon.InitializeDatabase() +111
   Hakon.HamiltonCargo.Web.NinjectWebCommon.Start() +124

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +260
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +34
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +288
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +785
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(Boolean designerMode) +58
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +82

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +877
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +169
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +133
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +125
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +731

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1590.0
```

Comment: try searching using this `ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674

Comment: Do you mean that the same connection string from Azure SQL database could work on your local side? I assume that this is a connection issue, could you provide the connection string related configuration in your app.config/web.config file? Also, please check username and password from the connection string your configured under App Settings of your Web App could successfully access your Azure SQL database.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that I used this same connection string on my local app and everything is work (I only needed add firewall exception on Azure database). And username and password is good too, checked on SQL Managment Studio and on this local app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was two keys in generated connection string by Microsoft.. You must set to "Persist Security Info" and "TrustServerCertificate" keys value: "True".

Answer (score 3):

In my case, **net core 3.1**, I was trying to connect supplying the connection string through `Configuration.GetConnectionString`, that is stored in **appsettings.json**, the password had unicode values and the json file was saved in an encoding other than UTF-8. So, to solve the problem I had to save the json file in UTF-8 encoding and it worked.

Comment: Also beware of the single slash that have been converted into two slashes ( \ -> \\ ).

Answer (score 0):

For my case issue was appearing because I was trying to copy/paste *SQL DB* connection string from the Database **"Connection Strings"** section to Web API **"Application Settings->Connection strings"** section without setting the connection string `User ID` and `Password` values, i.e:

[image]