# Azure Devops - Database unit test login failed for user

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to get the Azure Devops unit test task configured and working but appear to be hitting an issues regarding failure to login. The unit tests work when run on the local machine connected to the Azure Sql database and the user name and password have been tested successfully against the azure sql database server directly in SSMS.

I've tried a variety of workarounds such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260500/azure-login-failed-for-user) but to no avail. What could possibly be the issue if access is ok.

[image: zure]

Comment: If your tests require a database to run, they are **not** unit tests. Unit tests run in isolation with no dependencies.

Comment: Ok @daniel Mann - see the following link regarding SQL unit test execution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/scripts-in-sql-server-unit-tests  If you can help with the question, that’d be appreciated.

Comment: @DanielMann. Funny, i am unittesting my database. I think i need a database to run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the app.config as follows in the screenshots and that appeared to address the issue. Specifically in the connection string, I opted to select the level of authentication required.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [Accept your solution as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)